# Determine General Solution for ODE by Inspection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of :
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2x$$

i) By inspection trial solution

ii) By separating variables

iii) Verify that your answer is correct

I tried to integrate it by multiply both side by dt and I acquire $x(t)=-2xt$ but the answer provided is $x(t)=e^{-2t}$

And for part 2 the provided answer given is $x=e^{-2t}+c$
but i got is

[My answer for part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Qhw.jpg)

Comment: did you treat $x$ as constant with respect to $t$ when you integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are treating $x$ as a constant with respect to $t$, but $x$ is a function of $t$. When you solve by separation of variables you get
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2x \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{x}=-2dt $$
and integrating you find
$$\log \lvert x \rvert=\int \frac{dx}{x} = -2\int dt=-2t+c.$$
Hence 
$\lvert x \rvert = e^{-2t+c}$.

Comment: so when i want to move x i should only bring nothing but x over to the other side is it? Sorry, I am not very good in math

Comment: Yes. Notice that you can do this only if $x \neq 0$. On the other hand, $x = 0$ is a trivial solution, and by Cauchy theorem no other solution intersects $x=0$. That means every other solution $x=x(t)$ never vanishes, so you can divide by $x$.

Comment: alright, understood. Thank you very much for your time. Cheers